# Cropping logic results in black image

Tags: php, php-gd

Struggling to get the math correct for image cropping, hoping someone else is able to see my issue. It appears to be overshooting the dimensions of the image leaving 1 pixel of the original image on the left of the result.

```php
function thumbnail_create($file, $w, $h, $crop = false, $output_filename = null, $output_dirname = null)
{
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize(FILESPATH . $file);
    $r = $width / $height;

    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width - ($width * abs($r - $w / $h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height - ($height * abs($r - $w / $h)));
        }

        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w / $h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h * $r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w / $r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }

    $mime = mime_content_type(FILESPATH . $file);
    $handler = "imagepng";

    if (in_array($mime, ["image/gif"])) {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif(FILESPATH . $file);
        $handler = "imagegif";
    } elseif (in_array($mime, ["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"])) {
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg(FILESPATH . $file);
        $handler = "imagejpeg";
    } elseif (in_array($mime, ["image/png"])) {
        $src = imagecreatefrompng(FILESPATH . $file);
    }

    if (!isset($src) || !$src) {
        return false;
    }

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagealphablending($newImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($newImage, true);

    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    if (!empty($output_dirname)) {
        make_dir($output_dirname);
    }

    // BUILD OUTPUT PATH/FILE
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (empty($output_filename)) {
        $output_filename = str_replace("." . $ext, '-thumb.' . $ext, basename($file));
    }

    if (empty($output_dirname)) {
        $output_dirname = dirname($file);
    }

    $output = $output_dirname . '/' . $output_filename;
    $handler($newImage, FILESPATH . $output);

    return $output;
}
```

```
thumbnail_create('news/feature/fluffy-kitty.png, 100, 100, true)
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Original width: int(862)
Original height: int(192)
Cropped width: float(-2146)
Cropped height: int(192)

Comment: first you can get the mime with the `getimagesize()` function

Comment: second the option 'imagealphablending($newImage, false)` and `imagesavealpha($newImage, true)` only works with `png` i guess

Comment: So better to save the image as `.png` with `imagepng()`  rather than using handler.

Comment: Thanks! I just added handler just in case it was causing the problem. It was usually using imagepng. If you zoom in on the "after" image.. you'll notice on the left there is 1px of the original image but the rest is black, so I think the `$width` and/or `$height` are incorrect when `$crop` is true

Comment: Yeah they are, width is coming back as negative (see update)